# Redis - setex - value is not an integer or out of range

Tags: redis

The following used to work fine:

`redis_client.setex(key, expiry_in_sec, value_json)`

And now it suddenly returns:

***value is not an integer or out of range***

Answer (score 8):

The issue is between the different redis clients.

When working with `StrictRedis`, the `setex` syntax is:

`setex key, expiry, value`

When working with `Redis` client, the `setex` syntax is:

`setex key, value, expiry`

our specific problem was that someone changed the redis client.

Comment: the solution can be found in here as well: https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/issues/260

Answer (score 2):

Redis will also return this error if the time value (or expiration time) is a `float` instead of an `int`.

In my case, using Redis in Python, I had to change the following:

#### Causes Error

```py
ex = expiration_delta.total_seconds()
```

#### Fixed

```py
ex = int(expiration_delta.total_seconds())

success = redis.set(name=redis_key, value=my_val, ex=ex, nx=True)
```

*Note the `ex` argument to `set()` makes it work like `setex`.*